# code execution does not stop on the break point

Tags: debugging, uft-api

I am doing the API Automation in UFT 12.54. In the event code section, I have some lines of code, but while debugging, execution does not stop on the breakpoint.

Does any one have solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below action will solve the problem

Tools -> Options -> API Testing -> General

"Run test in debugging mode" needs to be checked in.